# JavaScript - Set onmouseover for multiple elements without using :hover

Tags: javascript, events, hover

Is there any way I can do this by not using :hover and by not adding "onmouseover and onmouseout" in all elements, like an effective way in a script witch sets onmouseover and onmouseout for all input elements.

NOTE: Please try with JavaScript before trying with JQuery

---

```
<head>

    <title>123</title>

    <style>

    .button {
    color: red;
    }

    .button:hover {
    color: blue;
    }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div>

        <input class="button" type="button" value="1">

        <input class="button" type="button" value="2">

        <input class="button" type="button" value="3">

    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

Loop through all the elements with the `input` tag

```
a=document.getElementsByTagName('input')
for (i in a){
   a[i].onmouseover=function(){/* code goes here */}
   a[i].onmouseout=function(){/* code goes here */}
}
```

With jQuery:

```
$('input').on('mouseover',function(){/* code goes here */}).on('mouseout',function(){/* code goes here */})
```

Comment: Yes, but if i want to set the color by doin: this.style.color = "red" how shall i define the this?

Comment: You might want to double check your for loop. You should really use a conventional for loop rather than a for..in, but even ignoring that you don't use I within the loop...

Comment: @Murplyx: Replace the comment block in the anonymous function (the `code goes here`) part with that code

Answer (score 3):

Not that I recommend this, but you could try putting an event handler for `mouseover` on the body element and then use `event.target` / `event.srcElement` to determine whether you want to handle the event or not

```
document.body.addEventListener("mouseover",function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    var targetElem = e.target || e.srcElement;

    // you can use a switch on the nodeName and handle event
    switch(targetElem.nodeName) {
        case 'INPUT':
            // do something
        break;
    }
},false);
```

Sample JS Fiddle (with background color change) http://jsfiddle.net/Rcgx5/

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
window.onload=function(){
    document.onmouseover=function(e){
        var e = e || window.event, el = e.target || el.srcElement;
        if(el.type == 'button') el.style.color='red';
    };

    document.onmouseout=function(e){
        var e = e || window.event, el = e.target || el.srcElement;
        if(el.type == 'button') el.style.color='black';
    };
};
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/wqvRt/)