# Get index of e.target child inside eventlistener

Tags: javascript

How exactly do I get the index of e.target? IndexOf wont work and I dont want to use the Array.prototype property. So what is the best way to get the index of the target element?

Basically element is a container with a bunch of divs. If I hover over a div I want to get its index.

```
element.addEventListener("mouseover", someEvent, false);


function someEvent(e) {
    if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
        // get the index of the hovered element here
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

I explicitely stated that I dont want to use Array.prototype so the link is not a duplicate.

By the way, here a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nbjve593/

Comment: Get the index in relation to what exactly ?

Comment: @adeneo I thought the code makes it clear. Basically element is a container with a bunch of divs. If I hover over a div I want to get its index.

Comment: No, that's not clear, `addEventListener` only works on one single element

Comment: @adeneo you do know what im doing here right?

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing, you claim to be using `addEventListener` on a container full of DIV's, but that's not possible

Comment: @adeneo I never said I was. Im making use of the bubbling effect.

Comment: ...of the what now? So the index in relation to what then, when using the "bubbling effect" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript DOM: Find Element Index In Container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761881/javascript-dom-find-element-index-in-container)

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14787248/javascript-set-onmouseover-for-multiple-elements-without-using-hover

Comment: @adeneo, if I understood correctly: you are trying to get position of child element within parent node

Comment: @adeneo I do it just like that if I have multiple event listeners. I add the event listener to the parent then during the event chain you'll get the correct e.target

Comment: @LGSon not a duplicate. I made it clear that I dont want to use the Array.prototype property. I know how to solve it using Array.prototype.slice.call but Im not interested in doing so for this particular problem

Comment: Can you please show your HTML? That way we can see what you're trying mouse-over, and the element(s) of which you're trying to find the index. As it is you're trying to explain code to us, as well as explaining your intent//requirement. Reduce your work: *show* us your [MCVE] code. Also, *why* don't you want to use `Array.prototype.slice.call()`? If you can explain the requirements that might help us to provide better answers (although, admittedly, sometimes using an approach you don't want to use remains the best way, but not always).

Comment: @Asperger, not Array.prototype.slice.call, this: Array.prototype.indexOf

Comment: Okay, if you know how to do it with `[].slice.call` show us that code, what would you convert to an array to use `indexOf` on,  in the code above?

Comment: Another possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378365/finding-dom-node-index

Comment: May I ask **for what** you need the index ?

Comment: @DavidThomas https://jsfiddle.net/nbjve593/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `mouseover` event doesn't have an `index` property and you don't want to use `Array.prototype` methods, here is an alternative

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll('#container-id div');

for(i=0; i < els.length; i++) {

  els[i].index = i;

  els[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    
    e.target.innerHTML = e.target.index;

  }, false);
}
```

```css
#container-id div {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container-id">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

**Update**

If you have thousands of child elements you might want `Array.prototype.indexOf` anyway.

This version use `children` instead of `childNodes`, to avoid getting all the text nodes.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('container-id');

  el.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    
    var p = e.target.parentElement;
    var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(p.children, e.target);
    
    if (e.target !== el) {
      e.target.innerHTML = index;
    }

  }, false);
```

```css
#container-id div {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container-id">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Initial source: [Finding DOM node index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378365/finding-dom-node-index)

Comment: As an answer to your comment: I dont need the index for any particular reason. Im just trying to learn new techniques.

Comment: What you are doing is not a good idea. You are applying an eventlistener to all of those children. Also I would cache the length in the for loop but that wouldnt make the performance any better. Imagine you would have 1000 divs and you have to apply an eventlistener to each of them.

Comment: @Asperger: *please*, if you're still actively interested in doing this, show the code you're working with. Without your HTML and JavaScript (and the requirements you need the answers to meet) it's very hard to provide anything other than best-guesses. **Please** help us to help you.

Comment: @DavidThomas ok hang on. I will do this, sorry for not having posted enough infos.

Comment: @Asperger That is a pretty normal, and recommended, way to do it, unless, as you commented, you have thousands of elements, ... then you have to consider alternatives to get the index, and the Array.protoype methods suddenly becomes your friend again.

Comment: @Asperger Updated answer with a 2:nd approach, which is already suggested amongst the comments and my 2:nd possible dupe link, though I used `children` instead of `childNodes` to avoid text nodes

Comment: Oh well. I thought there were other ways as well. Accepted since you were the only nice guy here.